# Shared Web Hosting provider for video or social networking sites

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, shared-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I found some web hosting service providers who provides very cheap shared hosting services with a lot of features which are generally not available with other hosting providers like Video Scripts Hosting, Social Network and Community Website hosting etc.

- arvixe
- pacifichost
- cirtexhosting

But the downside is, I never heard their name before. I visited many review sites as well but no one wrote about them.

If someone who had experienced them before or knows some other good shared web hosting providers for  Video Scripts Hosting, Social Network and Community Website hosting etc. then please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

In case of video script hosting, my personal experience with arvixe and [cirtex](http://www.cirtex.com/) hosting is good. Both are reputable hosts and are enough for the video hosting needs. As for social networking script, what type of script you're planning ? is it buddypress or dolphin ?dolphin or similar other social network scripts that allow video uploads should be hosted on FFMPEG servers like [arvixe](http://www.arvixe.com/) and cirtex are recommended. Shared hosting with no-ffmpeg feature will only hog memory and you're likely to run out of resource from your shared hosting account.So if your requirement is video hosting then it's better to choose FFMPEG enabled hosts.

Comment: I hadn't planned about any specific social networking script to install. Perhaps I'll make my own or i'll transfer my existing site thinkzarahatke after adding some features. I am surprised that both providers haven't picked by maximum reviewers.